# ionic serve command error and ionic address command empty result

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I have got this **ionic serve** command problem that I just get this error **Hmm,we can't reach this page** and when I try to see the result of **ionic address** command, I get nothing to see. I don't know what is the problem in here. Please someone assist. Thanks

Comment: is this error displayed in console?and does ionic serve leads to blank page?.....

Comment: this error displayed in browser which was in myipaddress:port number and the content is Hmm, we can't reach this page

Comment: can u see what's displayed in console(inside devloper tools)........also is there any error displayed in terminal after doing ionic serve?

Comment: no there is no error displayed in both the console and the terminal. Both looks great but then if I put ionic address command it gives an empty output.

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
"serve:before": "watch",
"emulate:before": "watch",
"deploy:before": "build",
"build:before": "build",
"run:before": "watch"

  }
```

make sure that package.json (inside scripts )has all the above mentioned lines........